# CMake cannot resolve runtime directory path

Tags: cmake

After running cmake CMakeLists.txt

I get the following warning

```
CMake Warning at src/CMakeLists.txt:32 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target MMPEditor because
  files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

runtime library [libQt5Widgets.so.5] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
  /home/ch/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib
runtime library [libQt5Core.so.5] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
  /home/ch/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib
runtime library [libQt5Gui.so.5] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
  /home/ch/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib
runtime library [libQt5OpenGL.so.5] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
  /home/ch/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib
```

Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.

What does it mean for one file to be hidden by another and how can I allow CMake to determine which is the right folder to link to?

Comment: It's a warning, not error.

Answer (score 17):

What the warning actually implies:

1. The project requests linking with the **shared library**, which is contained in **two directories**. That is, both these directories have the file named like `foo.so.x.y`.
2. CMake **perfectly understands** which library file is chosen for linking. That is, it may pass the **"right" directory** to the runtime loader, so the loader will search the library there.
3. For some reason, CMake **cannot prevent** the loader to search under the **"wrong" directory** too. E.g. that directory is searched by default, or it contains other libraries needed for the same executable.
4. As a result, CMake **cannot guarantee** that, when you run the executable, the loader will find the proper library.

For examples, the message

```
runtime library [libQt5Widgets.so.5] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
  /home/ch/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib
```

means, that the project requests to link with the library `libQt5Widgets.so.5` located in the directory `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

But library with the same name exists also in the directory `/home/ch/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib`, which CMake treats as "implicit directory", where the loader will search in any case. (Probably, because this directory is listed in the variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`).

The consequences of the warning:

1. The project can be **configured** without the errors.
2. The project can be **built** without errors.
3. But when run the executable, the loaded **may** load wrong library. And that could lead to **unpredictable results**.

Because unpredictable results on running are rarely acceptable, it is better to fix the warning. Possible ways include the following:

0. Make sure that CMake chooses the library which you are **actually intended** to use.

   E.g. you could actually intend to use the custom installation of QT under `/home/ch/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64`. In that case you need to hint CMake about your intentions. E.g. by setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable.
1. **Uninstall** the library located in the "wrong" directory.

   E.g. if you have newer version of the library and never intend to use the older one, then for avoid confusion it is better to uninstall the later.
2. If the "wrong" directory is searched by the loader because it is included into the variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, then set this variable to not contain that directory.

   CMake is able to correctly build projects for run without `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` settings.
3. If "wrong" directory is searched by the loader because it contains some other libraries, **eliminate usage** of that libraries in your executable.

   If you have two "repositories" of libraries on your PC, then compatibility between libraries is guaranteed only within a single repo. Mixed usage of libraries could lead to incompatibility problems at runtime.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks for all the insights. Definitely should be the accepted answer here.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, nice response. A question for my case: what if the conflicting library is in a subfolder of the folder which contains the intended-to-be-used library? I cannot "uninstall it" as in step 1) as I do not have privileges

Comment: @velenos14: You may try to adjust `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable to not contain directory with the conflicting library, as described in the step 2.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, can you please have a look on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76318677/libtorch-and-cuda-stub-library-loaded-at-runtime-problem ? Thank you!

Comment: Nice answer. 
I still don't understand:
1) Does action #0 *ensure* that Cmake will choose the correct library? If not, what other actions would do so? 
2) Does action #2 *ensure* that the loader will choose the correct library? If not, what other actions would do so? 
3) What specific actions/commands would help in item #3, in case action #1 is not an option.

Comment: A couple of questions:
1) I guess that when one configures the system so that cmake links against the same library that is loaded upon execution, the warning would still show up, is that correct?
2) How can one tell which library is loaded upon execution? What tools/commands show this? If I am correct in #1, one would need to use such tools to make sure.

Answer (score 10):

### If you're dealing with `find_library`

`find_library(LIBRARY_NAME PATHS "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)` where

- `PATHS` stands for the exact path to the libs
- `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` means, that cmake will not search anywhere else

check the values of lib and include paths with `message(status, ${LIBRARY_NAME})`

---

### If you're dealing with `find_package`:

It's a bit more complicated than the previous example, but it's essentially the same.

For each package you have to run `find_package` for:

1. Create file with name `Find<Packagename>.cmake`, e. g. if you're looking for cppunit, you'll have to create `FindCPPUNIT.cmake`.
2. In that file, you'll have to run `find_path` on include files and `find_library` on lib files, like in "If you're dealing with `find_library`".

   ```
   find_path(CPPUNIT_INCLUDE_DIR PATHS "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)       
   find_library(CPPUNIT_LIBRARY PATHS "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
   ```

   And then you have to add the path to the file to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.

Comment: The error is not about finding wrong library, so adding parameters for `find_library` or `find_package` change nothing. You may even **hardcode** path to the library, but the warning remains.

Answer (score 5):

Your system libraries are conflicting with your local custom build Qt libraries. Its a warning but you might not get expected results in your application because of this. You need to tell CMake that it should exclude system path while searching for libraries in your CMakeModule. From [this documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3afind_library)

> If NO_DEFAULT_PATH is specified, then no additional paths are added to
>   the search.

Also in same documentation one more flag is mentioned `NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH` which only include platform specific default paths.

Comment: Those are flags to find_library right? What if you are just using find_package - how do you set the search paths for a particular target?