# CMake Warning: Cannot generate a safe linker search path for target

Tags: c++, linker, cmake

While running CMake for a pcl project I got a warning message:

```
-- Configuring done
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:12 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe linker search path for target
  handgenerator_output_to_pcd because files in some directories may conflict
  with libraries in implicit directories:

    link library [libboost_system.so] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libboost_filesystem.so] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libboost_thread.so] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libboost_date_time.so] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libboost_iostreams.so] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libboost_serialization.so] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libboost_chrono.so] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.

-- Generating done
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Looks like you have 2 `Boost` installations. One of which in the directory implicitly searched by the linker, but you explicitely tell the project to use another installation. Why you need that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake cannot resolve runtime directory path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536567/cmake-cannot-resolve-runtime-directory-path)