# CMake omit libraries passed to 'target_link_libraries'

Tags: makefile, cmake, linker, linker-errors

I have a set of custom libraries I'm trying to build using CMake files I wrote. The current directory structure looks like this:

```
├── lib
├── src
│   ├── ac_d
│   ├── at_d
│   ├── bp_d
│   ├── fm_d
│   ├── hm_d
│   ├── pi_d
│   ├── pv_d
│   ├── ra_d
│   └── rc_d
└── test
```

My goal is to have the compiler use the .so files built in the `./lib` directory when linking the executables in the `./src` directory. I've tried the following, to no avail:

In top level CMakeLists.txt:

```
/* minimum version, project name etc */

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

/* other stuff */
set(CDH_LIB_NAMES comm daemon debug tty sock)

set(CDH_LIB_INCLUDES
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/global.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libcomm.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libdaemon.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libdebug.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libtty.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libsock.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/uthash.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/utlist.h)

add_subdirectory(lib) # make sure we build .so first
include_directories(lib) # then use this as an include directory
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib) # and a link directory
find_library(CDH_LIBS
    NAMES tty comm sock debug daemon
    PATHS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib"
) # Not sure if this does anything
add_subdirectory(src) # Now build the src binaries
```

I also heard that you can use `target_link_libraries()`, so I added lines similar to this in all `src/*/CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(ACD_BIN ACdtest)
set(ACD_SRC
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ACd.c
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ACd.h
        ${CDH_LIB_INCLUDES})
add_executable(${ACD_BIN} ${ACD_SRC})
target_link_libraries(${ACD_BIN} ${CDH_LIB_NAMES})
```

For some reason I still get undefined references. So I tried compiling one such binary with `make VERBOSE=1 pi-d` and got the following output (only relevant lines for brevity):

```
Linking C executable pi-d
cd /home/user/projectname/build/src/pi_d && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/pi-d.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  --std=gnu99     CMakeFiles/pi-d.dir/PId.c.o  -o pi-d  -L/home/user/projectname/lib -rdynamic ../../lib/libcomm.so ../../lib/libdaemon.so ../../lib/libsock.so -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/projectname/build/lib:/home/user/projectname/lib
```

Which looks like it's only getting `libcomm`, `libdaemon`, and `libsock`, neglecting `libdebug` and `libtty`. Why is this the case? What can I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by simply renaming the target to `debug_lib`.

```
add_library(debug_lib SHARED ${DEBUG_LIB_SRC})
```

This causes the library made to be called `libdebug_lib.so`, but that's fine for my purposes.

Answer (score 2):

`debug` is a **keyword** for [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/target_link_libraries.html) command.

Linking with libraries followed that keyword is performed only for "Debug" configuration, which probably is not your case.

Comment: I'm attempting to implement the answer you gave over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39662985/linking-against-a-library-called-debug-in-cmake and running into the issue of "cannot find -ldebug_lib", which seems like something is getting lost in translation.