# Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target caffe because files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit directories

Tags: cmake

I am trying to install this code https://github.com/NVlabs/ssn_superpixels but get an error at the `cmake ..` step

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CUDA_cublas_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "caffe" in directory /home/haziq/ASTAR/scripts/ssn_superpixels/lib/video_prop_networks/lib/caffe/src/caffe
```

So I deleted the build folder, recreated it and cd into it and ran `cmake .. -DCUDA_cublas_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcublas.so.9.1` but now get the following messages.

```
CMake Warning at src/caffe/CMakeLists.txt:20 (add_library):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target caffe because files
  in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit directories:

    runtime library [libsnappy.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /home/haziq/anaconda3/envs/ssn/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.


CMake Warning at src/caffe/test/CMakeLists.txt:29 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target test.testbin because
  files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    runtime library [libsnappy.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /home/haziq/anaconda3/envs/ssn/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.


CMake Warning at tools/CMakeLists.txt:14 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target extract_features
  because files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    runtime library [libsnappy.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /home/haziq/anaconda3/envs/ssn/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.


CMake Warning at tools/CMakeLists.txt:14 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target device_query because
  files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    runtime library [libsnappy.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /home/haziq/anaconda3/envs/ssn/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.


CMake Warning at tools/CMakeLists.txt:14 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target convert_imageset
  because files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    runtime library [libsnappy.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /home/haziq/anaconda3/envs/ssn/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.


CMake Warning at tools/CMakeLists.txt:14 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target test_net because
  files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    runtime library [libsnappy.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /home/haziq/anaconda3/envs/ssn/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.


CMake Warning at tools/CMakeLists.txt:14 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target net_speed_benchmark
  because files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    runtime library [libsnappy.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /home/haziq/anaconda3/envs/ssn/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.


CMake Warning at tools/CMakeLists.txt:14 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target compute_image_mean
  because files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    runtime library [libsnappy.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /home/haziq/anaconda3/envs/ssn/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.


CMake Warning at tools/CMakeLists.txt:14 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target train_net because
  files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    runtime library [libsnappy.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /home/haziq/anaconda3/envs/ssn/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.


CMake Warning at tools/CMakeLists.txt:14 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target finetune_net because
  files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    runtime library [libsnappy.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /home/haziq/anaconda3/envs/ssn/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.


CMake Warning at tools/CMakeLists.txt:14 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target
  upgrade_net_proto_binary because files in some directories may conflict
  with libraries in implicit directories:

    runtime library [libsnappy.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /home/haziq/anaconda3/envs/ssn/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.


CMake Warning at tools/CMakeLists.txt:14 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target
  upgrade_net_proto_text because files in some directories may conflict with
  libraries in implicit directories:

    runtime library [libsnappy.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /home/haziq/anaconda3/envs/ssn/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.


CMake Warning at tools/CMakeLists.txt:14 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target
  upgrade_solver_proto_text because files in some directories may conflict
  with libraries in implicit directories:

    runtime library [libsnappy.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /home/haziq/anaconda3/envs/ssn/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.


CMake Warning at tools/CMakeLists.txt:14 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target caffe.bin because
  files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    runtime library [libsnappy.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /home/haziq/anaconda3/envs/ssn/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.


CMake Warning at python/CMakeLists.txt:9 (add_library):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target pycaffe because files
  in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit directories:

    runtime library [libsnappy.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /home/haziq/anaconda3/envs/ssn/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.
```

I found a post here [CMake cannot resolve runtime directory path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536567/cmake-cannot-resolve-runtime-directory-path) that provides a solution for `find_library` and `find_package` but mine is `add_library`. Anyway I tried fixing the first CMake warning

```
CMake Warning at src/caffe/CMakeLists.txt:20 (add_library):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target caffe because files
  in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit directories:

    runtime library [libsnappy.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /home/haziq/anaconda3/envs/ssn/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.
```

by editing line 20 of src/caffe/CMakeLists.txt by replacing `add_library(caffe ${srcs})` with `add_library(caffe ${srcs} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)` but now get this message.

```
CMake Error at src/caffe/CMakeLists.txt:20 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:

    NO_DEFAULT_PATH

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1):

install libcublas 10 then run again