Local install vs install for CPack generator
If we rerun cmake after make install in our project, we get CMake warnings
Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target ... because
  files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    runtime library [libtiff.so.6] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
   ...

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.

This is because make install copies installed libraries to another location (/usr/local/lib) that is also in our LD_LIBRARY_PATH [1].
The root cause for this is that we are confounding two different uses of the install command: For local installation, and for generating binary installers.
For local installation (compilation and installation on the same machine), we should install only our own artifacts, not third-party library dependencies that are already installed on our system.
For generating binary installers, however, we need to copy our own shared libraries and those we depend on to the same lib/ directory.
How to disentangle these two cases? Should we make the install statements conditional on a CMake option?
Disclosure: Previsouly posted to no avail at the CMake forum [2].
[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/69742501/1017348
[2] https://discourse.cmake.org/t/local-install-vs-install-for-cpack-generator/10815

Since you want to implement two variants of installation (with 3d-party libraries and without them), CMake option seems to be the right tool for switching between these variants. Well, for provide different installation sets there is a COMPONENT option of install command, but I don't see how it could help in your case since make install unconditionally installs all components.

Also, for the installation variant with 3d-party libraries consider to install them privately for your package. E.g. under ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/<your-package-name>/ subdirectory. That way given libraries won't conflict with the ones installed system-wide, and CMake warning about "safe runtime search" won't be emitted. (For load private libraries your executable needs to have appropriate RPATH; CMake provides appropriate mechanisms for setting RPATH.)

@Tsyvarev, thank you for these helpful comments, which clearly go into the right direction. Could you possibly paste them as an answer, just expanding the bit about the "appropriate RPATH"? I would then quickly accept, and come back with more specific questions if needed.
